# How to authorize an internal server (no public URL) OAuth 2.0 origin for a Google API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-client

When creating an OAuth 2.0 client id for use with a Google API, one must add an authorized origin by providing a server's URL (at the Google Developer Console -> Api & Auths -> Credentials tab).

However, my server does not have a public URL. [This page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide)  mentions this and suggests using localhost, but I tried that and it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a public URL, a private page that only you can access will work as well.